# Compilation Issue with Scala Netbeans Plugin

Tags: scala, plugins, netbeans

I'm having trouble compiling a basic Scala project under Netbeans 7.0 using the Scala plugin.

> /Users/user/NetBeansProjects/ScalaTestApplication/nbproject/build-impl.xml:236: Problem: failed to create task or type scalac
>   Cause: The name is undefined.
>   Action: Check the spelling.
>   Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
>   Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: did you try setting the $scala_home environment variable?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure scalac is in your path
2. Make sure SCALA_HOME is set in your environment
3. Add -J-Dscala.home=/your/scala/install to the netbeans_default_options in the etc/netbeans.conf file in your netbeans install